# how to use jquery ajax success data

Tags: ajax

I'm constantly running into an issue where i am unable to use the ajax success data to perform another function. as per below

```
$("#addproperty_state").keyup(function(){
    var vardata = $(this).val();
    var urlPro ="<?php echo HTTP_PHP; ?>ajax_common.php?action=get_area&area="+vardata;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlPro,
        dataType: "text",
            async:false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#statelist').html(data);
            }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

I want to now use the result of the ajax call so that i can populate another text box with the result value.

```
$("#statelist li").click(function(){
    var statename = $(this).attr("title");
    $("#addproperty_state").val(statename);
});
```

but if i was now to click on the li nothing happens. How can i use the ajax result to actually do something else with it?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function:

```
$("#statelist li").live("click", function(){
    var statename = $(this).attr("title");
    $("#addproperty_state").val(statename);
});
```

It works for elements that get added to the dom later on